# Не передаются данные с помощью GET

Tags: php

После регистрации, прльзователю на почту приходит ссылка, для активации аккаунта, ссылка выглядит следующим образом:

```
$valid_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");    
                    $valid_row = $valid_sql->fetch_assoc();
                    $id_act = $valid_row["id"];
                    $messageEmail = $mess." <a href=https://mysite.com/activate.php?login=".$login."&id_act=".$id_act.">link</a> ".$mess1;
```

Но проблема в том, что id_act по какой-то причине не вставляется в ссылку, но логин на месте

```
echo $id_act;
echo $login;
```

Выводят то что нужно, но опять же, id_act в ссылке не присутствует. В чем причина?

Comment: может помочь кто-то?

Comment: Надо экранировать переменные

Comment: может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 0):

- Нужно экранировать все переменные перед тем как использовать их в
  запросах к БД.
- `<a href="link"></a>` - link должен быть внутри    кавычек, так как
  это атрибут html тега.

  ```
  $valid_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");    
  $valid_row = $valid_sql->fetch_assoc();
  $id_act = $valid_row["id"];
  $messageEmail = $mess.' <a href="https://mysite.com/activate.php?login='.$login.'&id_act='.$id_act.'">link</a> '.$mess1;
  ```

Comment: проблема не в этом